# Error when using jar but not in the library itself

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I built a Java library to send message in IBM MQ.

It is working fine when I execute the code on the library project.

However, when I use the `.jar` into another tool (JMeter), an error occurs.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiFactory.getInstance(Lcom/ibm/mq/jmqi/JmqiThreadPoolFactory;Lcom/ibm/mq/jmqi/JmqiPropertyHandler;)Lcom/ibm/mq/jmqi/JmqiEnvironment;
    at com.ibm.msg.client.mqlight.MQLightComponent.getImplementationInfo(MQLightComponent.java:220) ~[mq-jms-8.0.0.3.jar:8.0.0.3 - p800-003-150615.2]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.getVersion(Trace.java:1692) ~[mq-jms-7.0.1.3.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.createFFSTString(Trace.java:1650) ~[mq-jms-7.0.1.3.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.ffstInternal(Trace.java:1536) ~[mq-jms-7.0.1.3.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.ffst(Trace.java:1444) ~[mq-jms-7.0.1.3.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(JmsFactoryFactory.java:209) ~[mq-jms-7.0.1.3.jar:7.0.1.3 - k701-103-100812]
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.initialiseMQConnectionFactory(MQConnectionFactory.java:3325) ~[mq-jms-7.0.1.3.jar:7.0.1.3 - k701-103-100812]
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.<init>(MQConnectionFactory.java:274) ~[mq-jms-7.0.1.3.jar:7.0.1.3 - k701-103-100812]
    at my.package.MQ_Manager.createConnection(MQ_Manager.java:36) ~[my-jar.jar:?]
    at my.package.MQ_Manager.<init>(MQ_Manager.java:27) ~[my-jar.jar:?]
    at my.package.Producer.<init>(Producer.java:18) ~[my-jar.jar:?]
    at my.package.Request.sendRequest(Request.java:116) ~[my-jar.jar:?]
    at my.package.Request$sendRequest$2.call(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:14) ~[?:?]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:321) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:72) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:223) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler.sample(JSR223Sampler.java:71) ~[ApacheJMeter_java.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_31]
```

Corresponding code:

```
MQConnectionFactory factory = new MQConnectionFactory();
factory.setHostName(properties.getProperty("HOST"));
factory.setPort(Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("PORT")));
factory.setChannel(properties.getProperty("CHANNEL"));
factory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
factory.setQueueManager(properties.getProperty("QUEUE_MANAGER"));
factory.setAppName(properties.getProperty("APP_NAME"));
Connection connection = factory.createConnection(properties.getProperty("APP_USER"), properties.getProperty("APP_PASSWORD"));
connection.start();
return connection;
```

Error occurs at this line `MQConnectionFactory factory = new MQConnectionFactory();`

Any idea? Thank you.

**Update 1**

To create the `.jar` I :

1. Clicked on `Export`
2. Selected `Runnable JAR file`
3. Selected `Extract required libraries into generated JAR`

**Update 2**

Moreover when I built the Jar, I get this warning. Do you think that is important?

> This operation repacks references libraries. Please review the licences associated with libraries you wish ti reference to make sure you are able to repack them using this application. Note also that this operation does not copy signature files from orignal libraies to the generated JAR file.

Comment: Does your `jar` contain the proper libraries it depends on (or did you add those manually to the classpath of `jmeter`)?

Comment: @second Thank for your answer. Yes I think else the error should occured at the first line not at the end of the method.

Comment: Can you add the complete stacktrace?

Comment: @second I put the stacktrace in the question.

Comment: Can you provide a list of all dependencies that are in the classpath (from your jar and from jmeter itself)? Maybe there are multiple versions of this class in different jars?

Comment: I already checked and there is no common libraires (for ibm.mq). I updated my question. Thank you.

Comment: Seems the chat link isn't create automatically anymore. Well anyway [`here`](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201664/discussion-between-royce-and-second) it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After disccussing the issue with the `OP` I went ahead a verified the issue myself.
The result is that its working for me ...

**Step 1:**
Created a maven project with included the following code

```
package test;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory;

public class JmeterTest {

    public JmeterTest() {
    }

    public void test() throws JMSException {
        MQConnectionFactory factory = new MQConnectionFactory();
        factory.setAppName("myApp");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

**Step 2:**
Exported this from eclipse as runnable jar and copied into JMeter (`\lib\ext\`).

Note that a export with library handling `package required jars into generated jar` does not work. Use `Extract into generated jar` or `Copy into subfolder` (and then copy the jars from the subfolder into `\lib\ext` as well).

related dependecies are:

```
com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.0.4.0.jar
bcokix-jdk15on-1.57.jar
bcprov-jdk15on-1.57.jar
javax.jms-api-2.0.1.jar
```

**Step 3:**
Started JMeter and created a ThreadGroup with a `JSR223 Sampler`.

```
import test.JmeterTest;
new JmeterTest().test();
```

Then started the test. No error occurred.

**Step 4:**

Instead of exporting a library, you could directly (after adding the dependencies) add the required code into the script panel:

```
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory;

MQConnectionFactory factory = new MQConnectionFactory();
factory.setAppName("myApp");
```

Worked as well

---

Conclusion: Interference from other dependencies on the jmeter classpath are the likeliest cause of the issue.

Comment: Thank you ! Indeed the problem was caused by other packages (`jmqi` and `mq-jms`). So JMeter executed code from these packages and not from mine. Solution has been to remove these packages.